# Render a General Link in Sitecore with target="_blank"

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore I have a `General Link` which is set as an external link. What is the simplest way for me to render this link so that I get `target="_blank"` on my page and it opens in a new window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a General Link field, and you'd like it to hold a reference which is to open in a new window. If that's the case, the image below should answer your question:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Yan said about configuring the link in Sitecore, if you need code to render it, you can do it with a `FieldRenderer` or in C# with the API to access the field.

e.g.

```
<sc:Link Field="Your Field Name" runat="server" />
```

or

```
<sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Your Field Name" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code as well, in the case you have a framework built over the Sitecore API

```
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer fieldRenderer =
    new Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer();

fieldRenderer.Item = MySitecoreItem;
fieldRenderer.FieldName = "Link";
return fieldRenderer.Render();
```

The "Link" hardcode is specific to Sitecore for the system supplied Link template and you can reuse that in your code.

`MySitecoreItem` is a type of `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`.

I encountered the problem where I could get the URL from the item by saying `LinkManager.GetItemUrl()`, but I couldn't get the css classes that were embedded in the link template without getting out regex or `String.Split()` after asking for the `Item.Field[0].Value`.

The above method rendered the link out to a string that I could write directly to the browser and would work as you'd expect an anchor tag to do.